# How to create check constraint with foreign key reference

Tags: sql, h2

I am creating a database with these two tables in H2:

```
CREATE TABLE INSTANCE
( 
     INSTANCE_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     DATE DATE, 
     TIME TIME, 
     LOCATION VARCHAR(255), 
     PRICE INT, 
     CAPACITY INT, 
     EVENT_ID INT
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION
( 
     RESERVATION_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     RESERVATION_ORDER INT NOT NULL, 
     INSTANCE_ID INT NOT NULL, 
     USER_ID INT NOT NULL
);
```

So for example there is an instance with capacity of 20.

Reservation order increments with each reservation to this instance.

So for example like this:

```
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (2,2,1,3);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (3,3,1,4);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (4,4,1,5);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (5,1,3,2);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (6,2,3,5);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES (7,1,6,6);
```

My problem is, that I need to create check constraint that

```
INSTANCE.CAPACITY >= RESERVATION_ORDER
```

so I cannot add another reservation, when there is already 20 of them made to that instance, but I have no idea how to do that. I used SQL only a few times in my life and I have a hard time referencing other tables with a foreign key.

I tried adding something like this when creating the table with no success

```
CHECK (RESERVATION_ORDER =< (SELECT CAPACITY FROM INSTANCE WHERE (INSTANCE_ID = INSTANCE_ID)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add table names or aliases to distinguish `INSTANCE_ID` column from table `RESERVATION` from the same column from the table `INSTANCE` in your check constraint. You also need a foreign key constraint.

```sql
ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD
    FOREIGN KEY (INSTANCE_ID) REFERENCES INSTANCE(INSTANCE_ID);

ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD
    CHECK(RESERVATION_ORDER <=
        (SELECT CAPACITY FROM INSTANCE I
            WHERE (RESERVATION.INSTANCE_ID = I.INSTANCE_ID)));
```

I think you should also check that `RESERVATION_ORDER` is greater than or equal to 1 by replacing `RESERVATION_ORDER <= (SELECT …` with `RESERVATION_ORDER BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT …`.

Most likely you also need a `UNIQUE` constraint to prevent duplicate rows in `RESERVATION` with the same `INSTANCE_ID` and `RESERVATION_ORDER` values.

```sql
ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD UNIQUE(INSTANCE_ID, RESERVATION_ORDER);
```

Please note that `FOREIGN KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints are always ensured, but `CHECK` constraints **with references to other tables** in H2 are validated only when you insert or modify the rows with the constraint. `CHECK` constraints in H2 aren't re-validated when tables referenced from its subqueries are modified. So you should either not decrease `CAPACITY` in existing rows in `INSTANCE` table, or perform some additional validation when you do that, for example, in a trigger.

Comment: I had a foreign key constraint, i just forgot to write it here. But this looks like the solution i was looking for thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a check constraint can only refer to columns *in the same row* or user-defined functions.

You may be able to do what you want by defining a user-defined functions.  Or you can define a trigger to enforce the constraint.

You cannot, however, do so with a simple check constraint.

The most common way to tackle this problem is the following:

1. Add a column to `reservations` which is the current number of active instances.
2. Add insert/update/delete triggers to `instances` and increment/decrement the aforementioned column appropriately.
3. Add a check constraint in `reservervations` that compares the calculated value to the computed count.

This check constraint will fail.

I prefer this approach over using UDFs in a check constraint because the count is easy to see and verify.

Comment: Yeah I tried to look into functions but I don't quite understand them. Could you please help me how to write one?

Answer (score 0):

You can define UDF and call that UDF on RESERVATION table. Something like below :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckInstanceCapacity (@event_id int, @capacity int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @value int
    SELECT @value = CASE WHEN CAPACITY >= @capacity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM INSTANCE
    WHERE EVENT_ID = @event_id 
  RETURN @value
END;

ALTER TABLE RESERVATION ADD CONSTRAINT InsCapacity 
CHECK (dbo.CheckInstanceCapacity(EVENT_ID, RESERVATION_ORDER) = 0);
```